# jquery contextmenu refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I got a result from the controller. This result is shown in a horizontal list and every listentry has it's own contextmenu and each category has a different list inside the Contextmenu

1. Category1

   - Insurer1, InsuranceType1, ContextMenu1
   - Insurer2, InsuranceType2, ContextMenu2
2. Category2

   - Insurer3, InsuranceType3, ContextMenu3

ContextMenu 1 and 2 has this itemlist:

- "mt1": { name: "example1" },
- "mt2": { name: "example2" }

ContextMenu 3 has this itemlist:

- "directly": { name: "Directly" },
- "sequence": { name: "Sequence" }

Now, I got the following problem:
If I click on the ContextMenu1 it's shown correctly but if the ContextMenu is open and i click on ContextMenu3 it will show the items from the ContexzMenu1. If i click first outside the ContextMenu that its closing and then clicking on the ContextMenu3 it will display correctly.

this is my jquery code.

```js
$("#ctxMenuElementMails").click(function (i, v) {
            $.contextMenu('destroy');
            switch (elem.InsuranceCategoryProgramCode) {
                case "HOUSEANDLIVING":
                    var item = {
                        "dghhdirect": { name: "DG: HH-Directly" },
                        "dghhsequence": { name: "DG: HH-Sequence" },
                    }
                    break;
                case "CARANDTRANSPORTATION":
                    var item = {
                        "dgmfdirect": { name: "DG: MF-Directly" },
                        "dgmfsequence": { name: "DG: MF-Sequence" },
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    var item = {
                        "exd1:" { name: "ExampleDefault1" },
                        "exd2:" { name: "ExampleDefault2" },
                    }
                    break;
            }
            $.contextMenu({
                selector: "i[name='context-menu-mailTemplates']",
                trigger: 'left',
                callback: function (key, options) {
                    var riskId = $(options.$trigger).data("riskId");
                    var customerId = $(options.$trigger).data("customerId");

                    switch (key) {
                        case "exd1":
                            var templateMt1 = GetMailTemplate("EMAIL1", riskId, customerId);
                            OpenMail("TemplateName", templateMt1.TemplateText, templateMt1.ContactEMailAddress);
                            break;
                        case "exd2":
                            var templateMt2 = GetMailTemplate("EMAIL2", riskId, customerId);
                            OpenMail("TemplateName2", templateMt2.TemplateText, 'someMail@mail.com');
                            break;
                        case "dgmfdirect":
                            GetExcelTemplate(customerId, riskId, "DGMFDIRECT");
                            break;
                        case "dgmfsequence":
                            GetExcelTemplate(customerId, riskId, "DGMFSEQUENCE");
                            break;
                        case "dghhdirect":
                            GetExcelTemplate(customerId, riskId, "DGHHDIRECT");
                            break;
                        case "dghhsequence":
                            GetExcelTemplate(customerId, riskId, "DGHHSEQUENCE");
                            break;
                    }
                },
                items: item
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctxMenuElementMails">contextmenu</div>
```

Comment: Can you add current working example with Code Snippet?

Comment: What/Witch Code Snippets do you need?

Comment: Code which you added in the question could be added as Code Snippet feature of SO

Comment: Now i got it. thanks sorry was a little bit confused.

Comment: The example given is not working as you explained in the question.